# RatingBar с градиентом

Tags: android

можно ли задать RatingBar цвет заполнения с градиентом как в примере внизу? [image: Пример дизайна RatingBar с градиентом]

Comment: вид такого бара вы можете [нарисовать абсолютно любой](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/ratingbar.php#custombar) хоть с градиентом, хоть в полосочку. это просто картинки. любые картинки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ.